# Finding and opening a file with vim in a single command alias in tcsh

Tags: find, alias, tcsh, backticks

I want to make an alias which would work like this:
`vf hello.c` would execute a find command to search for hello.c and open it in the vim editor.

What is the best way to do it? I've tried the following (doesn't work):

`alias vf "find -name $* -exec vi {} \;"`

`` alias vf "vi `find -name $*`" ``

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer after a trial n error:

Use `alias vf "find -name \!:1 -exec vi {} \;"`